# How to invert div between different rows bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to place my bootstrap `div` for my 3 type of screen:

For the web it must be like this :

```
 <div class="col-lg-8">A</div>  <div class="col-lg-4">B</div>
 <div class="col-lg-8">C</div>  <div class="col-lg-4">D</div>
```

for the tablets it must be like this :

```
 <div class="col-md-12">A</div> 
 <div class="col-md-12">C</div>  
 <div class="col-md-6">B</div><div class="col-md-6">D</div>
```

and for the phones it must be like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-12">A</div> 
 <div class="col-sm-12">B</div>  
 <div class="col-sm-12">C</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">D</div>
```

Is it possible to do that with bootstrap all in one ?

It's a lite bit tricky because the blocks **B** and **C** are inverted between the tablets and the phones. I try to use the `pull` class without result, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="b">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
      <div id="c">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div>D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var b = $('#b'),
    c = $('#c'),
    bContainer = b.parent(),
    cContainer = c.parent();

$(window).resize(function() {

  if($(this).width() > 768 && $(this).width() < 992) {

    b.remove();
    c.remove();
    bContainer.append(c);
    cContainer.append(b);

  } else {

    b.remove();
    c.remove();
    bContainer.append(b);
    cContainer.append(c);

  }

});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/YWZKby)

Comment: thanks a lot,can you explain me this notation please : [class^="col"] > div

Comment: I did it only to see this gray rectangles. `[class^="col"]` means: every tag which has class that begins with `col-` and `> div` means: every `div` that is direct children of `divs` with class that begins with `col-`

Comment: I saw that in the tablet mode the blocks in this order : ACBD and you do it in this : ABCD order you can do that ?

Comment: no sorry you did : ABDC and I want ACBD for the tablet mode

Comment: Ah okay, it can be difficult, I'll try.

Comment: Yes I know it's crazy ^^

Comment: I think it is possible only using JavaScript.

Comment: You can check JS version (more complicated than flexbox but it works).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `md-8` + `md-4` (can be `7` + `5`, all it matters is the sum is no more than `12`)

to change the order, you can use `order` from `flexbox` within the tablet `media query`

**Note:** You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `^=`  to select every `col-` to style every `col-*-*`

> **[attr^=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose first value is prefixed by "value".

```css
[class^="col-"] > div {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 20px 0
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: 100%
  }
  .row > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 1;
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .row div:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .row > div:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
      <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <div>D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-xs-12` and `col-md-12` are unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @ dippas Sorry I saw that in the tablet mode the blocks are in this order : ACBD and you do it with ABCD order do you know how to change that ?

Comment: @makshh try remove and you will see, actually it needs that.

Comment: Hmm I don't see the difference.

Comment: @dippas it's not exactly that but it gives me some ideas to solve it thanks

Comment: @fandro I improved a bit the answer, I was switching the widths of B/D, and the media query I just put some random values based on bootstrap

Comment: @fandro I still think my answer i is easier than using JS, but is up to you